# Gatsby — Hot reload not working with .MDX generated pages

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, hot-reload

**Issue**

- Gatsby hot reloading is not working when modifying CSS properties
  from Components that lives in generated `.MDX` pages.

**Goal**

- I want the ability to review changes made to Components using hot
  reloading.

I started playing around with MDX and Gatsby but, I am finding frustrating having to restart the server every time I want to preview changes made to the design of Components. Is there any workaround this issue?

Thank you in advance.